# Intellij Idea doesn't work the way it was working with thymeleaf / java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, thymeleaf, intellij-plugin

I've reinstalled intellij idea and noticed some changes while working with Java / Spring MVC / thymeleaf. The exact thing that now I can't actually see if `return "htmlFile";` in @Controller method exists. It was underlinning it at first, now it does not. The second thing is when I put something in Model with `model.addAttribute("book", book)` and trying to use "book" in html with thymeleaf it shows like "book" doesn't exists but when I run program I can see that "book" exist and I can even get it's name or whatever.
Do I need some kind of plugin installed or what?

[image: Controller]

[image: HTML]

Comment: Make sure you have all the required Spring / Jakarta EE plug-ins installed and enabled, some of them have to be installed manually and are not bundled: https://i.imgur.com/UCNOZbc.png
https://i.imgur.com/U7neExT.png. If it doesn't help, please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new and attach the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) + a sample project to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Didn't really help. I will contact jetbrains than. thank you!

Comment: Did you install the community or the commercial edition of IntelliJ? Thymeleaf is only supported in the commercial edition.

Comment: Hello! It's commerical edition. The problem is gone now. I'm going to add Solution to my post.

Answer (score 1):

The actual solution:

- Go to: File / Project Structure / Facets.
- Select Spring, click on plus and Add your Application context class.

My Application context class example:

```
package ua.yuriy.spring.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("your.main.thread")
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("your.main.thread.repositories")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext, Environment env) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/"); // You might want to change templates to views
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.driver_class"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("ua.yuriy.spring.models");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```